# QR factorization of tridiagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, tridiagonal-matrices

Assume I have an arbitrary $m \times m$ tridiagonal real matrix. Assuming I'm using the Householder method, how many FLOPs are needed to get its QR factorization? How would one calculate it?

Comment: you already have a tridiagonal matrix?

Comment: You should use Givens method. With it you can nullify matrix entries one at a time, which is interesting for matrices that have already many zeros. It should be possible in $\mathrm{O}(n)$.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis , yes the mxm matrix can be assumed to already be tridiagonal.